# Within the context of creating animated GIFs, what is the CRF?

Tags: gif, compression, animated-gif

Occasionally, I see the initialism **CRF** used in the context of creating animated GIFs. Within the context of computer graphics and image compression, how do people define the term **CRF**?

Answer (score 1):

**CRF** - Constant Rate Factor | **CFR** - Constant Frame Rate -- they are *video* terms.

> ([link](https://streaminglearningcenter.com/encoding/saving-encoding-streaming-deploy-capped-crf.html#:%7E:text=Constant%20rate%20factor%20(CRF)%20is,numbers%20delivering%20higher%20quality%20scores.)) **Constant Rate Factor (CRF)** is an encoding mode that adjusts the file data rate up or down to achieve a selected quality level rather than a specific data rate.

> ([link](https://support.riverside.fm/hc/en-us/articles/5590128550813-What-are-constant-frame-rate-CFR-video-files-#:%7E:text=Constant%20Frame%20Rate%20(CFR)%20video%20files%20are%20tracks%20that%20are,easy%20to%20edit%20the%20video.)) **Constant Frame Rate (CFR)** video files are tracks that are designed for editing on video software. These files are encoded to stay synchronized with other CFR tracks, making it easy to edit the video.